# Safari, iFrame, changing Address Bar to iFrame URL

Tags: iframe, paypal, mobile-safari

I have a form that when you click submit it goes to another .php page whose entire goal is to load a iFrame with a URL pointing to paypal.  This enables us to have customers enter CC information without their CC information ever touching our servers (to stay in compliance)

the problem I'm having is strictly with Safari on iPad (and probably iPhone also but I haven't tested that yet)

When the 2nd page loads after clicking the form button, it changes the address bar to the URL of the iFrame, rather than loading the iFrame with its URL.

This causes the page to give an error about the securetokenID being wrong and makes it so the customer cant proceed.

I have a email into paypal about this but I figured I'd stop here and ask if anyone else has this issue and knows a way to solve it.

All the posts I've found were from 2013 about a similar issue and they claimed that paypal doesn't support mobile and you have to access paypal another way.   I'm hoping that now since its 2 years later there is an easier solution for getting Safari to load a iFrame in the page rather than change the Address Bar to the iFrames URL.

The iFrame code looks like this:

```
<iframe src="https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com?SECURETOKENID=vvqhqn8hwfi9poo2zcbm4xi4xevaq7hbfbyz&SECURETOKEN=8WjBh0buSd0WLc0FJRSOXwgS9" id="paypal_iframe" name="paypal_iframe" scrolling="no" width="480px" height="540px"></iframe>
```

So when I click on the form button, and its supposed to go to signup_2.php, it does for a split second then "redirects" to the URL in the iframe, which of course doesn't load properly because paypal is expecting it in a iframe.

This only happens on safari on a apple mobile device.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: PayPal has long blocked display of forms that can collect sensitive information inside iframes. I believe they are relaxing this restriction on some browsers that have implemented certain security features, but I'm guessing that you are hitting PayPal iframe-breaking code that they are quite intentionally applying in mobile safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the PayPal Developer Site, here is some information on the Hosted Checkout Pages and Mobile Optimization:

> PayPal’s hosted checkout pages are mobile optimized for iPhone, iPod and Android devices. This mobile optimized experience is available for all 3 Layout templates A, B and C. In the case of Layouts A and B, PayPal will auto-detect if the checkout page is being viewed from a supported mobile browser and will redirect to the mobile optimized checkout page. For Layout C, PayPal does not automatically redirect mobile users to a mobile optimized flow. The reason is that if PayPal automatically showed a mobile optimized embedded template, within a merchant web page that may not be mobile optimized, this can create unexpected and undesirable results. To display the mobile checkout page for Layout C, you must detect the supported mobile browser and then explicitly pass the form post parameter: TEMPLATE=MOBILE.

This comes from the [PayPal Payflow Gateway Developer Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#hosted-pages-and-mobile-browsers)

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I missed that when I was reading the documentation.